# AMPscript - if statements

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've question about AMPscript.
I have if statement as below it is working but if one of the value will be empty then we will have a gap in email. Do you know if there is solution for that?

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@x) THEN]%% 1nane: %%=v(@x)=%% %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@y) THEN]%% 2name: %%=v(@y)=%% %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@z) THEN]%% 3name: %%=v(@z)=%% %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@w) THEN]%% 4name: %%=v(@w)=%% %%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: What do you want it to do in case it’s empty?

Comment: @zuzannamj thanks! I've already fixed that. I had to edit html code and put <br> in another place :)

Answer (score 1):

Going off the question, I am assuming you want to control the numbering you have on `name` being displayed. So below is best I can think of to handle that without interruption to your current process:

```ampscript
%%[SET @nameCount = 1]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@x) THEN]%% 
  %%=v(@nameCount)=%%name: %%=v(@x)=%%<br> 
%%[SET @nameCount = ADD(@nameCount,1) ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@y) THEN]%% 
  %%=v(@nameCount)=%%name: %%=v(@y)=%%<br> 
%%[SET @nameCount = ADD(@nameCount,1) ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@z) THEN]%% 
  %%=v(@nameCount)=%%name: %%=v(@z)=%%<br> 
%%[SET @nameCount = ADD(@nameCount,1) ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@w) THEN]%% 
  %%=v(@nameCount)=%%name: %%=v(@w)=%%<br> 
%%[SET @nameCount = ADD(@nameCount,1) ENDIF]%%
```

But I would instead recommend doing the following to make it simpler and easier for maintenance:

```ampscript
%%[
  SET @nameStr = CONCAT(@x,"|",@y,"|",@z,"|",@w)
  SET @nameRS = BuildRowsetFromString(@nameStr,"|")
  SET @count = 1

  FOR @i=1 TO RowCount(@nameRS) DO
    SET @row = Row(@nameRS,@i)
    SET @field = FIELD(@row,1)
    IF NOT EMPTY(@field) THEN]%%
      %%=v(@count)=%%name: %%=v(@field)=%%<br> 
  %%[ SET @count = ADD(@count,1)
    ENDIF
  NEXT @i ]%%
```

This will utilize a FOR loop for the output as it is the same in general for each, with a couple variable entries. It also makes editing and modifying easier as it only needs to be done by adding a new CONCAT parameter (e.g. `,"|",@a`) and it will then correctly output your expected content. And if you need to make a change to the output, you only have a single place, not multiple, meaning you reduce risk of human error by ensuring its uniform output and not potentially miss one or incorrectly edit one, etc. (for example, how in your question you have the first one `@x` saying `nane` instead of `name`.)

Comment: thanks! :) actually in my case it was just about <br> because I put it in a wrong place and when the field was empty there was not necessary spacing  between the rows. But thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: @natalia - Glad you were able to solve it! Would you mind putting your solution into a self answer and marking it as correct for others to reference if they have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily it was small thing. I just needed to update html code and 
 so it was before not after endif. Thanks to that there is no spacing between the rows if for example name 3 is empty.

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@x) THEN]%% 1nane: %%=v(@x)=%% <br> %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@y) THEN]%% 2name: %%=v(@y)=%% >br> %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@z) THEN]%% 3name: %%=v(@z)=%% <br> %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@w) THEN]%% 4name: %%=v(@w)=%% <br> %%[ENDIF]%%
```